# How to connect multiple redash servers with single database

Tags: amazon-web-services, redash

We are using one Redash server as a Analytics tool and We all know each redash server should comes with its own db i.e postgres . So now I want to create a multiple redash servers and all the remaining servers should connect to single db within any one of the redash server ..? Inshort. SingleDb should be shared across multiple servers ....Can I know how Can I achieve it ..?

Thanks in Advance